# Both QSpinBox's buttons increment its value when using a custom stylesheet

Tags: qt, qt-designer, qtstylesheets, qtwidgets, qspinbox

I need to style `QSpinBox` like this:

[image: QSpinBox that I need]

But when I did it with stylesheet, both `down-button` and `up-button` were incrementing value, where `down-button` should have decremented it.

Stylesheet:

```css
QSpinBox {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 2px;
}

QSpinBox::up-button, QSpinBox::down-button {
    width: 40px;
    height: 50px;
    subcontrol-origin: border;
    subcontrol-position: top right;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

QSpinBox::up-arrow, QSpinBox::down-arrow {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}

QSpinBox::up-button {
    image: url(:/icons/ui/images/icons/arrow-up.svg);
    margin-right: 40px;
}

QSpinBox::down-button {
    image: url(:/icons/ui/images/icons/arrow-down.svg);
    margin-left: 2px;
}
```

When I placed `up-button` on top, and `down-button` on bottom, they worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place `up-button` on the right, and `down-button` on the left.

This requires splitting their stylesheets, and adding a `margin-right` to `down-button` with the value of `up-button`'s width.

Minimal **necessary** stylesheet that keeps the buttons laid out horizontally, separated, and functioning. Build from this step by step, and go back one step when it stops working:

```css
QSpinBox {
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

QSpinBox::up-button {
    border: 1px solid red;
    subcontrol-position: top right;
    width: 30px;
}

QSpinBox::down-button {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    subcontrol-position: top right;
    width: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
```